# Question about asynchronous execution order in JS

Tags: javascript

```
var flag = false;

function a() {
    foo();
}

function b(){
    $.getJSON(URL, '', function(data){
        foo();
    }
}

function c() {
    if (flag == true){
        return;
    }   

    flag = true;
    document.frm.submit();
    flag = false;
}

<span><a href="#top" onclick="a(); return false;"> TEST 1</a></span>
<span><a href="#top" onclick="b(); return false;"> TEST 2</a></span>
```

The goal is to prevent the form from being submitted twice, and because of other reasons it is not possible to disable the button or link itself, we used the flag variable.

The TEST 1 button only happens once when you click on multiple times, but the TEST 2 button is occasionally submitted twice.

I wonder if calling the foo function in callback form when TEST 2 button is clicked produces this result.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable that keeps track of whether you've submitted the form yet.

```
var ifSubmit = false;

if (!ifSubmit) {
  document.frm.submit();
  ifSubmit = true;
}
```

The code above will only execute once. Use something along the lines of that.